# Java - Creating an object extending List

Tags: java, list, generics, casting, constructor

How can I create a list with a specified type argument?
For example:

```
LinkedList<Integer> list = createList(LinkedList.class, Integer.class);
```

I've tried creating a method for it, but the method doesn't include the type argument when creating the new instance.

```
public static <T, L extends List<T>> L createList(Class<L> listClazz, Class<T> valueClazz) throws Exception
{
    return listClazz.getConstructor().newInstance();

    //Instead of
    //  new L<T>();
    //does
    //  new L();
}
```

I hope my question is clear enough, thank you for any help.

Comment: you are mixing compile time with runtime , in runtime generics has nothing to do, why do you want to use reflection?

Comment: You can google for "java type erasure".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't do that. Generics have no business at runtime, so you can't create parameterized instance at runtime using reflection. At runtime, `LinkedList<Intege>` is just a `LinkedList`. The type information - `Integer` is erased at compile time through "type erasure". The point is, why would you like to do that?

Comment: If so, how can I get the type argument of a list?
I'm considering  making a method like so:

fillList(new LinkedList<Integer>());

But I would have to get the 'Integer' class from the list.

Comment: @Limeth Again, you can't get the type information at runtime. But for this case, there are workarounds using reflection.

Comment: I made a Storage class, which extends HashMap<String, Object> and basically allows to load data from YAML and MySQL. I'd use the method to deserialize a serialized list stored in a MySQL cell.

Comment: @Limeth Are you sure you have to extend `HashMap`? It would be better if you can go with composition.

Comment: May I ask why? This seems like an easy way, because `org.bukkit.configuration.MemorySection`'s getValues() returns a `Map<String, Object>`. What would be the benefits?

Comment: I should've mentioned that `YamlConfiguration` extends `MemorySection`.

Comment: @Limeth Well, I can't comment on bukkit related queries. Haven't used it.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> //Instead of
> //  new L<T>();
> //does
> //  new L();
> ```

The two "do" exactly the same thing. How do you know it "does" one and not the other? Type parameters are compile-time illusions for type-checking. They are not relevant in what the code "does". To create an instance of `LinkedList<T>`, you do not need to know what `T` is, because it doesn't really exist after type erasure.

I think the issue you are having has nothing to do with the code inside the function, but with the signature of the method. By the very fact that the method is declared as it is, and you are passing an expression of type `Class<LinkedList>` (the type of `LinkedList.class`) to it, `L` must be `LinkedList`, and since the method returns `L`, the compiler must consider its return to by type `LinkedList`. None of this has anything to do with the code inside the method.

If you want the method's return type to be considered as `LinkedList<Integer>`, then just pass in an expression of type `Class<LinkedList<Integer>>`. Simple, right? How do you get an expression of type `Class<LinkedList<Integer>>`? For one, you could do `(Class<LinkedList<Integer>>)(Class<?>)LinkedList.class`.

If that seems kind of bogus, it's because `Class` is fundamentally a runtime thing -- it allows runtime creation of an object from that class. Using it with Generics, a compile-time type-checking mechanism, is fundamentally flawed. There is just one class object in existence for any class, e.g. `LinkedList`. Is it `LinkedList` or `LinkedList<Integer>` or `LinkedList<String>`? Well, it could be all of these, in the sense the the `newInstance()` method could create any of them (there is no difference at runtime).